# Python dictionary items issue

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am using Python3 for validation of dict items. I am extracting some data from database and then comparing those data with some expected data for validation purpose. At the end, I would like to show all the observed data in a dictionary format (key:value). Say, I have the data observed_output[13], observed_output[14] and so on. How can I put those data all together in a one-line code without putting the manually one-by-one. The output I want is like 
  `observed_output= {13:observed_output[13], 14: observed_output[14]}`
I tried, observed_output= {k: v for k, v in observed_output.items()}. Din't work. Can anyone help?
Here is my code, for clarity:

```
def test1_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 13 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert observed_output[13]== (25.000024795532227,)
def test2_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 14 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert (observed_output[14])== (89.5999984741211,)
def test3_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 15 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert (observed_output[15])== (26.66666603088379,)
def test4_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 16 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert (observed_output[16])== (26.111459732055664,)
def test5_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 17 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert (observed_output[17])== (15.0,)
def test6_AdvOp_validtion():
    db_cursor = conn.execute("SELECT object_id, value, timestamp from bacnet_history where object_id = 18 order by id desc limit 1")
    for row in db_cursor:
            observed_output[row[0]]=row[1:2]
    assert (observed_output[18])== (t,)


observed_output= {k: v for k, v in observed_output.items()}
```

Comment: What is `observed_output`?  Is it a list?

Comment: I declared it as: observed_output={}

Comment: So it's already a dict?  I'm confused about where these values are coming from, and what form they're in before they're in the dictionary.  Could you share the code?

Comment: I have shared my code. As you can see, I have extracting the items one by one for validation purpose. Finally, I would like to show them all together where I am facing the issue.

Comment: I also tried getting all the values from database even before putting them into validation phase. That works but takes long time due to the database query in sqlite3. So, I am trying this way for efficiency of the code but stuck here.